# directory name created with a weird folder name

Tags: python, unix

I have the following code where as part of the code it tries to create a folder if it doesnt exist, I see the folder created with directoryname as "AYH9P4~H",it should be created whatever is in the text file "data_file.txt" which is "AU_1.2.333",any inputs on why it is created with folder name "AYH9P4~H",BTW , running this script on a linux box

```
import os

def getAU (aufilename):
    file = open(aufilename,'r')
    return file.read()

def main ():
    aufilename="data_file.txt"
    #ROOT_DIR - The reference android build used to make the builds
    AU=getAU(aufilename)
    if (os.path.isdir("/local/mnt/workspace/builds/" + AU)):
        print "Direcotry local/mnt/workspace/builds/" + AU + "exists"
    else:
        print "Directory doesnt exist,creating directory" + AU + "now"
        os.chdir("/local/mnt/workspace/builds")
        os.makedirs(AU)
    ROOT_DIR= "/local/mnt/workspace/builds/" + AU
    print "ROOT_DIR"
    print ROOT_DIR

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess would be, that `file.read()` actually returns everything including linefeed, and possible other characters. You need to sanitize the output of `file.read()` in any case.

Other thought is that if you're trying to create such a folder on a filesystem that doesn't support multiple extensions (you have multiple dots in the name) it will be borked too.

Comment: Well, for one you could start indeed with `strip()`. But you make an assumption that data_file.txt will always contain one line. What if it will have more than one?